# How to disable a selected time slot in custom product in Shopify?

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-template

Hello Shopify Developers,

I have added date picker and time select options for a custom product in Shopify.

[image]

The time options are (9AM,10AM, 11AM)

If for a particular date a particular time slot has been selected, that specific time should not be shown in the dropdown.

Do you have any idea about how to do this?

Best regards,
Siva.